# Error running edmgen on entity framework ssdl, csdl and msl files

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

I have created a Entity Framework mapping based on the book ["Microsoft Entity Framework in Action"](http://www.manning.com/mostarda/). The OrderIT DB is available for download from the link. I am on VS 2010 RC and this is my first serious try of EF. But I keep getting an error

> "Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.    Model.edmx"

I have broken the .edmx file into constituent ssdl, csdl and msl files and ran edmgen and it

> gives me the same error as shown
>   below.   EdmGen
>   /mode:ValidateArtifacts
>   /incsdl:OrderIT.csdl
>   /inssdl:OrderIT.ssdl
>   /inmsl:OrderIT.msl
>
> error 7001: Object reference not set
>   to an instance of an object.
>
> Validation Complete -- 1 errors, 0
>   warnings

Obviously something is wrong with the mapping but the error message gives me no details. Why I am getting this error and how to fix it ?

I have uploaded the [relevant files here](http://cid-a4656e15be97671a.skydrive.live.com/browse.aspx/.Public).

**Update**
I did the whole thing again and this time marked the Company class as abstract. Looked like it is working now. It maybe this is the issue but I am not certain as I am new to EF in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the Company class abstract and it build correctly. With my inexperience in EF and the error message not indicating any details I was stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you found a bug in the RC. You should [report it here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/content/content.aspx?ContentID=12362), as soon as possible.

That said, I'm not sure you actually need to do what you're trying to do. Can you explain what your goal is? For a simple case of using the EF, you should not have to run EdmGen manually.

Comment: I just followed the book to do a mapping between entities and tables. I used VS to create EDM, deleted the auto created entities, created my own entities and manually re-mapped them, exactly as in the book. The VS error output shows me the error. I then used edmgen and got the same error. I guess VS is using edmgen internally and just reporting whatever error comes up.